# Python Linear Regression - Error with data dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, linear-regression, stock

I am having a 1-dimensional error within my code. I'm attempting to create a linear regression on stock prices to predict a few months in the future and, frankly, I'm very confused. I've been tweaking this program for the last few hours and I can't seem to get it right.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Dec  5 20:45:06 2022

@author: samwa
"""
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
from pandas_datareader import data
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

HUM = data.DataReader('HUM', 'yahoo', '1970-01-01')
HUM.to_csv('HUM Stock Data.csv')

df = pd.read_csv('HUM Stock Data.csv')
df.shape
df = df['Open'].values
df = df.reshape(-1, 1)

df.shape
dataset_train = np.array(df[:int(df.shape[0]*0.8)])
dataset_test = np.array(df[int(df.shape[0]*0.8):])
print(dataset_train.shape)
print(dataset_test.shape)

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset_train = scaler.fit_transform(dataset_train)
dataset_train[:5]

dataset_test = scaler.transform(dataset_test)
dataset_test[:5]

def create_dataset(df):
    x = []
    y = []
    for i in range(20, df.shape[0]):
        x.append(df[i-50:i, 0])
        y.append(df[i, 0])
    x = np.array(x)
    y = np.array(y)
    return x, y


x = dataset_train
y = dataset_train
# Build dummy variables for categorical variables

x = pd.get_dummies(x)
dataset_train = pd.get_dummies(dataset_train)
dataset_test = pd.get_dummies(dataset_test)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

model = LinearRegression()
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (-1, 1))
y_train = np.reshape(y_train.values, (-1, 1))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test.values, (-1, 1))
y_test = np.reshape(y_test.values, (-1, 1))

model.fit(x_train, y_train)
predictions = model.predict(x_test)

fig = plt.figure(dpi=128, figsize=(10, 6))
plt.title("Humana Reality v Prediction", fontsize=16)
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=10)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.ylabel("Price", fontsize=10)
plt.plot(y_test, color='green', label='Original price')
plt.plot(predictions, color='red', label='Predicted price')
plt.legend(loc="center left")
```

I have updated the passage below with np.reshape

```py
model = LinearRegression()
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (-1, 1))
y_train = np.reshape(y_train.values, (-1, 1))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test.values, (-1, 1))
y_test = np.reshape(y_test.values, (-1, 1))
```

However I am still receiving the 1 dimensional data error. Furthermore, I don't believe my testing data is any good because when I run it the predicted value and the actual historical value nearly completely overlap. I could really use some help with this one, I'm definitely at a lose.

Error log below:

```
  File "C:\Users\s\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\construction.py", line 627, in _sanitize_ndim
    raise ValueError("Data must be 1-dimensional")

ValueError: Data must be 1-dimensional


runfile('C:/Users/s/Desktop/HUM to CSV.py', wdir='C:/Users/s/Desktop')
(8256, 1)
(2064, 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\s\Desktop\HUM to CSV.py", line 81, in <module>
    x = pd.get_dummies(x)

  File "C:\Users\s\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py", line 948, in get_dummies
    result = _get_dummies_1d(

  File "C:\Users\s\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py", line 972, in _get_dummies_1d
    codes, levels = factorize_from_iterable(Series(data))

  File "C:\Users\s\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 439, in __init__
    data = sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy)

  File "C:\Users\s\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\construction.py", line 576, in sanitize_array
    subarr = _sanitize_ndim(subarr, data, dtype, index, allow_2d=allow_2d)

  File "C:\Users\s\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\construction.py", line 627, in _sanitize_ndim
    raise ValueError("Data must be 1-dimensional")

ValueError: Data must be 1-dimensional`
```

Answer (score 0):

Not easy without a minimal reproducible example, with some mock up data included.

But see

```py
df=pd.DataFrame({'col':[1,2,3,1,2]})
df.values
#array([[1],
#       [2],
#       [3],
#       [1],
#       [2]])
pd.get_dummies(df.values)
# ValueError: Data must be 1-dimensional

df.col.values
# array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2])

pd.get_dummies(df.col.values)
#   1  2  3
#0  1  0  0
#1  0  1  0
#2  0  0  1
#3  1  0  0
#4  0  1  0
```

From what I see in your code, without running it, you are in the first case (single column, but yet, still a 2d-matrix of a single column). You want to be in the second case (a 1d-matrix of that column).

In your case, if depending on your data (seems to have no column names, and have only 1 column), you can `get_dummies` on `df[0].values`, or starting from your array, on `x[:,0]`

Unrelated side-note, but I can't avoid it: don't ever iterate over rows. There is always a better way. For example, here, I feel that what you are looking for is `np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`, to get a matrix of n rows and 50 columns, showing 50 subsequent values of x (and since that is just a view, you don't actually build a matrix).

So, I would

```py
df=pd.DataFrame({0:[1,2,3,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,2,2,1]})
def create_dataset(df, nhist=5):
    xdum = pd.get_dummies(df[0]).values
    nr,nc=xdum.shape
    xview = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(xdum.ravel(), shape=(nr-nhist, nc*nhist), strides=(nc,1))
    return xview, df[0].values[nhist-1:]
```

Plus, I think it solve your dilemma: you need 1 column to get dummies, but after that you need to but them in 50 (5 in my example) columns of dummies

See result, assuming previous `df[0]` are `x` and `df[1]` are `y`.

```
(array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=uint8), 
array([2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1]))
```